# Why doesn't this sql script execute?

Tags: python, sql

Hi I have the following python:

```
c = conn.cursor()

#get the account id for the specific user

actidSQL = "select id from accounts where user_id = (select id from auth_user where username = '%s');" % user
c.execute(actidSQL)
actid = c.fetchone()[0]
print actid

#fill the latencies table - currently not firing, not sure why?
latencies_sql = "insert into latencies(account, replier, sender, replyemail, origemail, replydate, origdate) select m1.account, c1.id as replier, c2.id as sender, m1.id as replyemail, m2.id as origemail, m1.date as replydate, m2.date as origdate from contacts c1, contacts c2, emails m1, emails m2 where m1.id > m2.id and m1.reply = m2.mid and m1.reply is not null and c1.id = m1.fr and c2.id = m2.fr and m1.account = %s and m1.account = m2.account;" % (actid)
print latencies_sql
c.execute(latencies_sql)
```

The first sql executes but the second doesn't. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Are you sure your "select m1.account..." returns anything at all?

Comment: i print out the sql query and then run it on the database directly and it works.

Comment: Your queries are subject to injection. Better use `c.execute(actidSQL, user)` resp. `c.execute(actidSQL, actid)` and leave the `%s` in the query, without `%` operator. (I assume it is MySQL, other DBs might require a `?` instead of a `%s`.)

Comment: Don't you get an error message?

Comment: PLEASE! Add more details! Errors? Which DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "The first sql executes but the second doesn't."? You get an error? Or is there no data in the DB? I assume that there is no data in the database and you are using MySQL. This is because you don't commit your changes. A `conn.commit()` at the end of your script should help.

Comment: bingo. i think this the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an invalid query problem. You're trying to run either 2 queries, or 1.5 queries in the same c.execute

You either want an insert

```
insert into latencies(account, replier, sender, replyemail, origemail, replydate, origdate)
```

Or a select

```
select m1.account, c1.id as replier, c2.id as sender, m1.id as replyemail, m2.id as origemail, m1.date as replydate, m2.date as origdate from contacts c1, contacts c2, emails m1, emails m2 where m1.id > m2.id and m1.reply = m2.mid and m1.reply is not null and c1.id = m1.fr and c2.id = m2.fr and m1.account = %s and m1.account = m2.account;"
```

Comment: so when i print this out to the console and then manually run it just as is, it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Joe No. He wants to insert the result from a query into a table. This normally should work perfectly.

Comment: Insert values from select is valid query (at least for sql server)

Comment: Ah. I wasn't aware that syntax was valid, I've always used something a bit more verbose, and it looked weird :)